# CKeditor not showing and some content cannot be saved - Symfony CMF

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, symfony-cmf

I have installed the CMF sandbox by following this tutorial: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/cookbook/editions/cmf_sandbox.html

I'm using Jackalope + Doctrine DBAL instead of Apache Jackrabbit and at first glance everything seems to be working.

The issue arises when I want to edit text. Editing h1 elements works fine but when I edit a block of text, the **CKeditor does not show** and in addition to that, the save button does not become clickable after making changes.

**I switched to the Hallo editor** and the main stuff (bold, italic etc. and save button) now works (links, image uploading don't work; the cancel button does not switch back to Browse mode when editing text and returns this error: *Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'*)

---

Same thing with the CMF standard edition.

You help is much appreciated, let me know if you need more information. Like I said, I followed the CMF doc step by step and all the assets seem to be properly installed under /web/bundles/cmfcreate/...

Comment: do you install in a web root folder or sub directory? CreateBundle had a bug until yesterday when not in root folder. and the online docs talk about version 1.0 but the master branch is the RC of 1.1. which did you use?

Comment: and do you see any js errors or http not found when loading the page?

Comment: I install assets in the web root folder and I am using the master branch. There are no js errors when loading the page. However, I just installed the CMF standard v1.0.0 to see if things worked and I get the following js error: uncaught exception: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "default" was not found at "/bundles/cmfcreate/vendor/ckeditor/styles.js?t=D6IE".

Comment: did you run all the console commands as specified in https://github.com/symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf-docs/blob/master/cookbook/editions/cmf_sandbox.rst? you need doctrine:phpcr:init:dbal doctrine:phpcr:repository:init cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug

Comment: Yes I did. The issue seems to be coming from CKeditor because almost everything works fine with Hallo and I have no issue loading blocks and pages content into the database. It's really weird.. I also checked all the CSS and JS paths generated and they're all ok...

Comment: Even the CKEditor ones

Comment: To rule out browser incompatibilities: Does it work on http://cmf.liip.ch ? If it does not, then its something with the browser version you have. If it does work, then your setup for some reason is different.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just re-installed the CMF standard edition v1.1 and everything works fine now. Who knows why haha. (by the way, nice work on the new demo, looks a lot nicer!)